# Display first zero in number

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, blazor

First time working with Blazor.
In my "database" I have something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPPA0.png)

I would like to display the mobile phone number like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d93vr.png)

I have a problem:

1. if the first number of the mobile phone is 0, it should be displayed, ex: 0912345678
2. if the first number is not 0, display as it is

Tried like this:

```
<div class="card-deck" >
    @if (Users == null) { 
    <div class="spinner"></div>
}
else {
    @foreach (var user in Users)
    {
        <div class="card m-3" style="min-width: 11rem; max-width:15.5%;">
            <div class="card-header text-lg-left">
                <h3 style="font-size: 1em">@user.FirstName @user.LastName</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top imageThumbnail" size="small" src="\images\usericon.png" />
            <div class="card-footer text-center">
                <button style="font-size: 0.8em" href="#" justify-content-center disabled class="btn btn-primary m-1 mx-auto">@user.Email</button>

                <button style="font-size: 0.8em" href="#" disabled class="btn btn-primary m-1 mx-auto">@user.MobilePhone.ToString("D1")</button>

                <button style="font-size: 0.8em" href="#" disabled class="btn btn-primary m-md-2 mx-auto">@user.Address</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     }
}
```

But nothing's changed.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

You have modelled MobilePhone as an `int` (or long).

But PhoneNumbers, InvoiceNumbers and ProductNumbers etc should always be `string`.

Phonenumbers can have various notations, like +31-12345678 , 123(555)7689

As a rule of thumb, if you can't (won't) do calculations with something then it should not be a numeric type.

And when you have made it a string you can do all sorts of string operations and validations.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!